# How to delete a character that has been output on a specific position in CMD?

Tags: c++, windows, cmd, output, handle

I am trying to make a simple program that reads a string and if it finds the given character it will highlight it in red.

I already know how to change the colour of a single character and I know \b exists but I am not sure how to make it delete a character in a specific position. For example, if the string is aaaBaaa and the given character is B, then B's colour must be changed to red.

The issue with this code is that it deletes all the other text, anyone knows how to fix this?

I have tried system("cls") and then print the entire string again but the specific character's color is changed but I don't think it's the best possible answer.

I have tried \b but it deletes everything below the string. For example, if we have 5 strings and we test the top string then the rest will be deleted.

So far this is my code:

```
char ch = '0'; // What is printed in case it finds nothing
for (auto x : test)
{
    if (x == 'X')
    {
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsoleOut, color); // if x == 'X' we set the color to red
        WriteConsole(hConsoleOut, &x, sizeof(x) / sizeof(char), &done, 0); // we print
        ch = 'X'; // for later use
        Sleep(3000); // to check if it turns red
        break;
    }
}
cout << '\b';
if (ch == 'X')
{
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsoleOut, 0x7); // set color to default
    WriteConsole(hConsoleOut, &ch, sizeof(ch) / sizeof(char), &done, 0); // print
}
else
{
    WriteConsole(hConsoleOut, &ch, sizeof(ch) / sizeof(char), &done, 0);
}
```

test is the string
ch is the character it should output in case the given number isn't found

Comment: I am 95% sure that clearing the screen then printing the whole thing again is the only solution. That's how all the command line scripts that I know of do it. But let's see if someone with more experience has something else to say.

Comment: If you can configure the console window to behave or emulate one of the smart terminal types, you can use the editing commands of that terminal type.  Some terminals actually have a delete command where a character  is deleted and the remaining characters are shifted left.  Research all the terminal types supported by your console and check out there control or escape sequences.

Comment: The most portable method is to reprint the line or screen.  Otherwise, make your application a GUI.  There are "cursor" packages (libraries) that may help.  Search the internet for "C++ cursor position library".

Comment: If you are using (as i right now expect) the normal windows console + you are fine with writing to the buffer directly (always): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleoutput
otherwise you only will be able to modify the current line as you already noticed